# How to a get specific part of an input in Python, and multi paragraph input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

This is a two-part question. I am working on making a Ti-basic emulator/translator in Python 3. What I want is to have something like:

```
0->N
while N<20
disp "example"
input "example",a
N+1->N
end
```

Which is the Ti-basic equivalent to this in Python:

```
for n in range(0,20):
    print("Example")
    a=input("Example")
```

In a more simplified way, I want it so if it says `Disp "example"` on line one, to translate it to Python as:

```
print((text in quotations after disp, "Example" in this case))
```

The two questions:

**One:**

How do I separate sections of an input, so that when whatever line it is that has `disp` knows to put `print()` and to put the area with quotations in the parenthesis of the print?

**Two:**

How do I get an input with multiple lines, so I don't have to type the Ti-basic line by line, per input, and to save it when I run it, like if you go to an online emulator?

Comment: For the parsing part, check out [PyParsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing)

Comment: Why not type it by line, in a while loop, and just have some termination condition, like an empty line?

Comment: @ScottColby If when I use PyParsing, how do I specify it to pick all words after the first one? because like python needing quotations for text only Ti-basic does too so like `disp "words"` is `print("words")`, `disp variable` is `print(variable)`, and `disp variable+1+variableTwo` is `print(variable+1+variableTwo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [] #Create a list to store your values
for n in range (0, 20):
    print('Example')
    a.append('Example') #Add 'Example' string to list
print (a) #See all items in the list
```

If you want user to key in inputs 1 by 1:

```
a = [] #Create a list to store your values
for n in range (0, 20):
    sample = input('Please key in your input: ') #Be aware that inputs are by default str type in Python3
    a.append(sample) #Add sample string to list
print (a) #See all items in the list
```

Comment: Yeah It might be helpful if you explained that a little more. I am a beginner in python, and hoping to use this as a learning experience. Edit: Ok I get It now thankyou

Comment: It is already very detailed in explanation. You have to run the code and try it out to understand. If your knowledge is not up to this level, you should take a Python beginner's course, https://www.learnpython.org/  to learn faster

Comment: @its_programing_not_coding Hey, please help to mark it as the correct answer, tick on the side of the post if this post helped you. Thanks

Comment: I know I just couldn’t last night because I wasn’t online sorry. Edit: oh and thank you again. You too lcc

Answer (score 1):

```
#Declare a list
a = []

#Set a range for loop where N<20.
for x in range (19): 

    #Display "Example"
    print("Example")

    #Append "Example" to your 'a' list.
    a.append("Example")

# printing the list using loop 
for x in range(len(a)): 
    print a[x]
```